# How to validate Stripe payment successUrl on server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

So the Payment process seems very straight forward:

```
<script>
            var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxx');
            stripe
            .redirectToCheckout({
                lineItems: [
                    {price: 'price_1xxx', quantity: 1},
                ],
                mode: 'payment',
                successUrl: 'https://xx.co/payment-cool/?product=x',
                cancelUrl: 'https://xx.co/something',
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
        </script>
```

But sure ppl will start to fake that `successUrl` to get stuff for free. So I some-have need to validate that `successUrl` server-side and make sure that the purchase was made.

I'm on node, but an example in any language will do. I could not find info in Stripe docs :(

Comment: If you check the callout in the blue box on this link [1] you will see that you should not control fulfilment through the success URL. One way is to listen for a webhook event for a successful checkout for example [2].


[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#create-checkout-session

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#payment-success

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't understand web-hooks. Why is calling them?

Comment: Ok. I understand them now :)

Answer (score 0):

As per documentations:

> Don’t rely on the redirect to the success_url alone for fulfilling
>   purchases, as:
>
> Malicious users could directly access the success_url without paying
>   and gain access to your goods or services. Customers may not always
>   reach the success_url after a successful payment. It is possible they
>   close their browser tab before the redirect occurs.

Strategies to verify payment are described in this section https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#payment-success